# How to reset ARCore?

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Is there any way to reset the ARCore Android SDK?

I found out in Unity we can call reset method for ARCore session. I tried to close the session, but it crashed. I tried to restart Activity, it works but in some phones it crashed again.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset an ARCore session using Kotlin for Android SDK use the following three methods in a certain sequence:

```
.pause()       // Pauses ARCore session

.close()       // Releases resources used by an ARCore session 

.resume()      // Starts or resumes the ARCore session
```

Let's see what official documentation [says](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Session#close()) about `close()` method:

> **`close()`** method will **take several seconds** to complete.
>
> To prevent blocking the main thread, call `pause()` on the **main thread**, and then call `close()` on a **background thread**. It is not safe to call methods on this session or other objects obtained from this session while the session is being closed and after the session is closed.

A snippet for closing session might look like this:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

public override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()

    if (session != null) {

        GlobalScope.launch {     // launch a new coroutine in BG and continue
            delay(2000L)         // non-blocking delay for 2 sec
            session!!.close()
            println("Closing...")
        }
        session!!.pause()
        println("Paused...")     // main thread continues while coroutine's delayed
        Thread.sleep(2000L)      // block main thread for 2 sec to keep JVM alive
    }
}
```

A snippet for starting a session again might look like this:

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
        
    try {
        session!!.resume()

    } catch (e: Exception) { 
        session = null
        return
    }
}
```